Continuity of random variable and its CDF relation in $R^d$
Problem. For random variables $X_1,...X_d$ with joint CDF $F$, show that for a fixed $x=(x_1,...x_d)\in R^d$, $F$ is continuous if and only if $$P(\bigvee_{i=1}^d(X_i-x_i)=0)=0.$$
(Note. $\bigvee$ is used for maximum)

Attempt. To understand this better, I looked at the simple case $d=1$ for which we have the result that $F$ is continuous if and only if $$P(X=x)=0.$$ A logical extension would have been the condition $$P(X_1=x_1,...X_d=x_d)=0$$
except that I have found an easy counter example for $d=2$ by putting $X_2=1-X_1$ where, $X_1$ takes values $0,1$ with probability $1/2$. Then, $F$ is not continuous although $P(X_1=1,X_2=1)=0$. So, it makes sense that the $d$ case condition "has something more".
To proceed with the proof, maybe we could write
$$P(\bigvee_{i=1}^d(X_i-x_i)=0)=0\Leftrightarrow P(X_1=x_1,X_2\le x_i,...X_d\le x_d)=0$$
without loss of generality. I thought this would lead me somewhere but I'm not even sure this can actually be written without loss of generality. A small hint would be great.

$F$ is continuous at $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ if and only if $F(x_1-h, \ldots, x_n-h) \to F(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.
The limit of the difference $\lim_{h \to 0} [F(x_1,\ldots, X_n) - F(x_1-h, \ldots, x_n-h)]$ is precisely $P(\bigvee_{i=1}^d (X_i-x_i)=0)$.

got it, thanks. A 12s difference between our answers.

Managed to prove it. Not deleting the question as I didn't find a duplicate.
Hint. If $\max_i X_i=x_i$, it means $X_i\le x_i$ for all $i$ and the equality holds for at least one $X_i$ so,$$P(\bigvee_{i=1}^d(X_i-x_i)=0)=P(X_1\le x_1,..X_d\le x_d)-P(X_1<x,..X_d<x_d)$$
